# Stroke deletion in finger paint

Tags: android, android-canvas

I'm developing a finger paint type of application . I want a erase functionality that delete a single full stroke (i don't want point by point or full screen deletion) I want exactly to delete the strokes(a single stroke is points between touch down and touch up). Is there any predefined method in the android canvas do this stroke deletion ?

Comment: Actually there is no concept of erasing or deleting using `Canvas`. instead consider redrawing by invalidating the `View`...

Answer (score 0):

Keep a list of all the strokes.  When you want to delete one, remove it from the list, invalidate your view, and recreate the canvas by walking through the full list of all strokes.

Comment: shall u suggest any example for this ?